# Create setup without writing to registry

Tags: .net, installation, registry, roaming

I need to make a setup for my .Net4 application. What I expect about installer is that it will just check if .Net4 Client profile is installed on target machine and if not it will deploy the .Net package and it will extract the app to directory where the setup was started.

I don't want to write anywhere else(app is "roaming" and runs from sd card for ex.) as  copying it to start menu or Program Files or write in to the registry. I just want to be able to run the app.

Can distribute the .Net4 Client profile with the setup(any licence limitations)?

Is it possible? How can I start? Thank you for replies.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it is possible. Just remove any registry and application entries in setup project. Easy.